# Test if the lines in file1 are a subset of the lines in file2

Tags: python, python-3.x, filecompare

I have tried searching for an answer online but unfortunately without success. Therefore I am asking here:

I am trying to figure out if all lines in `file1` are present in `file2`. Luckily I can just compare entire lines rather than individual words etc. Unluckily I am dealing with GB files so a few of the elementary solutions that I have tried gave me memory errors.

At the moment I have the following code which does not work. Some guidance would be much appreciated.

```
# Checks if all lines in file1 are present in file2
def isFile1SubsetOfFile2(file1 , file2):
    file1 = open(file1, "r")


    for line1 in file1:        
        with open(file2, "r+b") as f:

            mm=mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) 
            my_str_as_bytes = str.encode(line1)
            result = mm.find(line1.strip().encode())
            print(result)
            if result == -1:
                return False
    return True
```

Sample file2:

```
This is line1.
This is line2.
This is line3.
This is line4.
This is line5.
This is line6.
This is line7.
This is line8.
This is line9.
```

Should pass if e.g. file1 is:

```
This is line4.
This is line5.
```

Should fail if e.g. file1 is:

```
This is line4.
This is line10.
```

Edit: I have just added a working version of my code for others benefit. No memory errors but its very slow.

Comment: Ick, your code is `O(m*n)`. It's trivial to do this in `O(m log m + n log n)`, and sometimes possible in `O(m + n)`

Comment: What you said about Algo complexity etc is above my head mate.

Comment: then before you learn *anything* else about programming, learn about algoritmic complexity and big-O notation. This is *important*.

Comment: Can you point me towards some layman articles for this please? Thx

Comment: wikipedia is pretty good: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms - but any decent textbook should cover it too

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it doesn't work but I think I know a way how you can solve it:

```
def is_subset_of(file1, file2):
    with open(file1, 'r') as f1, open(file2, 'r') as f2:
        for line in f1:
            line = line.strip()
            f2.seek(0)   # go to the start of f2
            if line not in (line2.strip() for line2 in f2):
                return False
    return True
```

This avoids opening the second file multiple times by always seeking to the start again for each line and at any moment you only hold 2 lines in memory. That should be very memory-friendly.

Another way (that could be faster) would be to sort both `file1` and `file2`. That way you could compare line by line and move to the next line in the other file if the string is lexically smaller than the one from the first file. Instead of `O(n**2)` that could be performed in `O(n*log(n))`. However that's much more complicated and I don't know if sorting GB of files makes sense (could use too much memory!).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that the mmap.find() does not give me a memory issue. It just doesnt do the matching correctly.

Comment: MSeifert, Yes your code worked. I gave you an up vote but it doesnt register as I have less than 15 reputation. However your code is much slower than the mmap solution that I posted above. I was basically missing a strip() from the string and thats why it wasnt doing the matching. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Ali Ah, so the `strip` was missing, at least something useful in the answer. If you found the solution yourself you can always post an additional answer here. It may be helpful for future readers.

Comment: I just did. Its still very slow compared to some thing like a unix diff. Do you think the search I am doing in mmap is the most efficient way of doing this or is there a better alternative? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with files that don't fit in memory is always hard.

If `file1` fits in memory but `file2` is too large, here is a solution:

```
# file1 and file2 are open file-like objects
unseen = set(file1)
for line in file2:
    unseen -= {line} # avoid exception from set.remove
#if unseen is empty, all lines were found in file2
```

Otherwise, you should sort (or perhaps CFBS-sort) at least one of the files.